# Comment a selection of line or block on VSCode

Tags: linux, windows, macos, visual-studio-code, comments

What is the shortcut for commenting the selected part of a line or block in `vscode`?

`ctrl+/` in *windows / linux* and `command+/` in *mac* comment the whole line/lines even you selected part of that line or block.

I used to use `ctrl+shift+/` in other IDEs.

Answer (score 0):

This type of commenting is mentioned as `Toggle-Block-Comment` and its short cut in `vscode` is `Ctrl+Shift+A` in *Windows / Linux* and `Shift+Option+A` in *Mac* but you can simply change it to `Ctrl+Shift+/` or `Shift+Option+/` because initially there is no command assigned to these keybindings in `vscode`.